# Mysql- unicode characters are fine but not accents

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I came accross a mind puzzling problem with mysql encoding today and would appreciate ideas on how to debug that further.

I had to update an old perl application, using mysql 5.6, which originally just in English and to which I had to add some unicode support (for khmer script).

I figured it would be best to do a test install. Took a dump of the prod db, imported into a test db, changed the charset of the tables that needed support to utf8 collate utf8_unicode_cli.

All worked well so went to apply to production. Ran the sql migration scripts to change charsets, deployed the new code and ... khmer characters do store/show fine but legacy è characters show as question mark with black square.

What really puzzles me is that

- test and prod run on the same (windows) box, same mysql server instance
- both test and prod databases have the same charsets et collation
- for the table in question, test and prod show create table statements are identical
- the same code connected to test works fine but connected to prod doesn't

I thought maybe the original data got mangled in the process so deleted it and reinserting it through the app interface. Still worked on test but not prod.

Same code works on test so code is probably not the issue.
Both on same server instance so probably not server config issue.
Khmer script works fine so probably not a utf "configuration" issue.
New data is wrongly handled so probably not a data migration/convertion issue.

So 2 questions:

- is the question mark with black square a sign of double encoding or just wrong encoding
- how can I debug this further? Anyway to see "raw" mysql stored data for example so I could compare?

Any input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Black Diamonds** with question marks,
one of these cases exists:

Case 1 (original bytes were *not* utf8):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8.  Fix this.
- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `INSERT` *and* the `SELECT` were not utf8/utf8mb4.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Case 2 (original bytes *were* utf8):

- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `SELECT` was not utf8/utf8mb4.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Black diamonds occur only when the browser is set to `<meta charset=UTF-8>`

---

Not relevant, but since you brought it up:

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.
This discussion applies to **Double Encoding**, which is not necessarily visible.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.